# tmux prefix keyboard shortcut version 3.0a

Tags: tmux

Please help for tmux version 3.0a
How do I enter these settings?
set -g prefix M-x bind M-x send-prefix
I can not find the file named .tmux.conf

Answer (score 0):

`tmux.conf` doesn't exist by default; tmux has its own built-in configuration. You'll need to create the file yourself. If you want your setting to exist for all users, place your config in `/etc/tmux.conf`; for user-specific settings, create `~/.tmux.conf`.

Per the [`tmux(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) manual page (under the `-f` option):

> By default, tmux loads the system configuration file from /etc/tmux.conf, if present, then looks for a user configuration file at ~/.tmux.conf.

Comment: I still have trouble executing commands on my tmux
Nothing happens when I run the default commands on my tmux, for example
ctrl + b + %
With these commands, I restored tmux to the default state
 set -g @plugin 'hallazzang/tmux-reset'